# Google TwoFA generating incorrect codes, synced time servers

Tags: c#, asp.net

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/403355/Implementing-Two-Factor-Authentication-in-ASP-NET?fid=1731001

using source above.

Using ASP.NET forms, C#

For some reason the codes generated do not match the ones on my phone(s), one phone is not synced well with the computers time but the other is. Even when checking 3 either side still having this issue.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked after I added this to `<configuration>` section of Web.Config:

```
<globalization culture="en-GB" uiCulture="en-GB" />
```